# Mover uma div para left ou right com a biblioteca Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Com o materialize eu sei que é so atribuir uma classe de nome "left" ou "right" a div, mas pelo bootstrap eu não sei como isso pode ser feito

Comment: Olá Richard Lopes, peço que explique melhor a sua pergunta. Se possível exemplifique com o que você está tentando fazer.

Answer (score 3):

Com o Bootstrap não é muito diferente, Richard. 
 Apenas utilize as classes pull-right e pull-left como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <img src="images/imagemUm.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">
            <img src="images/imagemDois.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar as classes `pull-left` e `pull-right` do bootstrap, ou usar o `float: left` e `float:right` no CSS mesmo.

Mais infos aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats